# How to return Generic View in SwiftUI

Tags: generics, swiftui

How can I achieve following in swiftUI as it's giving me following error:
Type `GenericView` cannot confirm to `View`; only struct/enum/class types can conform to protocols

```
struct MyView: View {
 let containerView: [String: GenericView] // Dictionary which holds sub-views

 init() {
    containerView = ["View1": View1(), "View2": View2()]
 }

 var body: some View {
  containerView["View1"] // ERROR HERE: Type `GenericView` cannot confirm to `View`; only struct/enum/class types can conform to protocols
 }
}

protocol GenericView { }

struct View1: View, GenericView {
   var body: some: View {
     Text("View1")
   }
}

struct View2: View, GenericView {
   var body: some: View {
     Text("View2")
     Text("View2 details")
   }
}
```

This View1, View2, View3.. etc can be inside `List` as follows and could avoid giant switch condition check for `viewModel.type`:

```
List {
  ForEach(viewModels) { viewModel in
   MyView(viewModel.type)
  }
}
```

Comment: The tool you're looking for is AnyView, not a custom protocol. (Though typically if you need this, you often should rethink your approach. This fights SwiftUI somewhat; SwiftUI typically is generic over the exact views, rather than using dynamic types. It's hard to see what problem you're trying to solve to know how to suggest redesigning. But if you really do need this, you need to use AnyView wrappers, not protocols.)

Comment: Hi Rob,  If I change dictionary value type to `let containerView: [String: AnyView]` after removing protocol, it give me error that `Cannot convert value of type View1 to expected dictionary value type AnyView`

Comment: You’d need ‘AnyView(View1())’

Comment: As aheze notes, all your types that you conform to GenericView will instead need to add an `AnyView{}` wrapper around the whole `body`. This is a bit inconvenient, but it also is something you generally shouldn't do.

Comment: Yes Ahez rightly mentioned.  Rob, could you please suggest better way to achieve this so I can return any types of view?

Comment: You cannot return any type of View. SwiftUI doesn't work that way. It optimizes based on knowing all the concrete types at compile-time. AnyView is the escape hatch if you absolutely cannot know the type. You need to rethink your design if AnyView doesn't match your needs. (It is somewhat controversial whether SwiftUI *actually* gets a lot of optimization out of knowing the types at compile-time, but it is designed based on that.)

Comment: In your example, you would implement MyView.body as `var body: some View { View1() }`, since clearly you do know the exact type. I assume your actual example is something else. How to redesign this depends on what that "something else" really is.

Comment: Note that using a Dictionary this way will generate other problems, since the subscript may return nil, and `body` cannot in any case return nil. No matter how you design this, you'll need to make sure you always return something. (EmptyView may be helpful here.)

Comment: Hi Rob, Thanks a lot for explaining it so deeply. The reason I am using dictionary since MyView return 8 types of Views (enum ViewType { case1...8}). So I am trying to remove big switch condition so to escape extending switch case for future views.

Comment: You can imagine `List` having different types cells (views). So instead of using switch condition I am trying to return View based on ViewModel type. I have added `List` example in my question at last.

Comment: AnyView is not the optimal solution for SwiftUI. Apple talked about that during WWDC this year. Instead we should favor @ViewBuilder's I believe that was found in this talk https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2021/10022/

Comment: Yes Jake. I am using ViewBuilder to return any view at other areas. I am quite not sure how I can achieve List view with various views bases on ViewModel type without using switch condition.

Comment: You can have a view accept Content where Content: View and use that as a switch container or a more generic wrapper around yet-to-be-specialized contents. If you have a bunch of different heights in a List you'll be pushing what the API wants to do anyway, though, likely leading to stuttery scroll just like in a TableView/CollectionView with dynamic heights that are calculated as cells display.

Comment: Thanks Ryan, could you please share some code to achieve above generic wrapper inside List? What I want is to remove switch condition so to have no dependency changing switch condition for new type of view if I move above code in Swift package.